# Queue implementation C++

Tags: c++, queue, implementation

Hi i am creating a queue for an assignment I have and I keep getting an output of " 4 4 4 4 4 ". I am not sure if I am personally doing the queue wrong on paper or if I messed up in the program. I just want to confirm if the Queue Does Really come out to that output. I included the Enqueue and Dequeue FIles. Thank You

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_SIZE = 100;

class QueueOverFlowException
{
public:
   QueueOverFlowException()
   {
       cout << "Queue overflow" << endl;
   }
};

class QueueEmptyException
{
public:
   QueueEmptyException()
   {
       cout << "Queue empty" << endl;
   }
};

class ArrayQueue
{
private:
   int data[MAX_SIZE];
   int front;
   int rear;
public:
   ArrayQueue()
   {
       front = -1;
       rear = -1;
   }

   void Enqueue(int element)
   {
       // Don't allow the queue to grow more
       // than MAX_SIZE - 1
       if ( Size() == MAX_SIZE - 1 )
           throw new QueueOverFlowException();

       data[rear] = element;

       // MOD is used so that rear indicator
       // can wrap around
       rear = ++rear % MAX_SIZE;
   }

   int Dequeue(int n)
   {
       if ( isEmpty() )
           throw new QueueEmptyException();

       int ret = data[front];

       // MOD is used so that front indicator
       // can wrap around
       front = ++front % MAX_SIZE;

       return ret;
   }

   int Front()
   {
       if ( isEmpty() )
           throw new QueueEmptyException();

       return data[front];
   }

   int Size()
   {
       return abs(rear - front);
   }

   bool isEmpty()
   {
       return ( front == rear ) ? true : false;
   }
};

int main()
{
   ArrayQueue q;

   int x =2;
   int y = 4;

   q.Enqueue(x);
   q.Enqueue(y);
   q.Dequeue(x);
   q.Enqueue(x+5);
   q.Enqueue(16);
   q.Enqueue(x);
   q.Enqueue(y-3);

   cout << "Queue: ";

   while(!q.isEmpty())
   {
       q.Dequeue(y);
       cout<<" " << y;
   }
}
```

Comment: You are just outputting the value of y on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: OT: `throw new QueueEmptyException()` should be `throw QueueEmptyException()`, and you can easily have `QueueEmptyException` extend `std::runtime_error`. The `cout << ...` inside the exceptions' constructors should not be there

Comment: Why does `int Dequeue(int n)` take a parameter? Did you plan on using it in the implementation?

Comment: Why doesn't `QueueOverFlowException` inherit from `std::exception`? Not saying that it *should*; just currious as the reason "why not"..

Comment: `rear = ++rear % MAX_SIZE;` looks odd. Can I interest you in a  nice, easy to follow`rear = (rear+1) % MAX_SIZE;`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code have following bugs.

1. In Enqueue, first rear should be incremented and then value should be inserted.
2. Dequeue function should not take any argument.
3. In main function you are calling Dequeue function in wrong manner. As Dequeue function returns integer so you should either store the return value in some variable or output directly to output screen using cout.

Correct code is:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    using namespace std;

    const int MAX_SIZE = 100;

    class QueueOverFlowException
    {
        public:
           QueueOverFlowException()
           {
               cout << "Queue overflow" << endl;
           }
    };

    class QueueEmptyException
    {
        public:
           QueueEmptyException()
           {
               cout << "Queue empty" << endl;
           }
    };

    class ArrayQueue
    {
        private:
           int data[MAX_SIZE];
           int front;
           int rear;
        public:
           ArrayQueue()
           {
               front = -1;
               rear = -1;
           }

       void Enqueue(int element)
       {
           // Don't allow the queue to grow more
           // than MAX_SIZE - 1
           if ( Size() == MAX_SIZE - 1 )
               throw new QueueOverFlowException();

           // MOD is used so that rear indicator
           // can wrap around
           rear = ++rear % MAX_SIZE;
           data[rear] = element;


       }

       int Dequeue()
       {
           if ( isEmpty() )
               throw new QueueEmptyException();

           int ret = data[front];

           // MOD is used so that front indicator
           // can wrap around
           front = ++front % MAX_SIZE;

           return ret;
       }

       int Front()
       {
           if ( isEmpty() )
               throw new QueueEmptyException();

           return data[front];
       }

       int Size()
       {
           return abs(rear - front);
       }

       bool isEmpty()
       {
           return ( front == rear ) ? true : false;
       }
    };

    int main()
    {
       ArrayQueue q;

       int x =2;
       int y = 4;

       q.Enqueue();
       q.Enqueue(y);
       q.Dequeue();
       q.Enqueue(x+5);
       q.Enqueue(16);
       q.Enqueue(x);
       q.Enqueue(y-3);

       cout << "Queue: ";

       while(!q.isEmpty())
       {
           cout<<q.Dequeue();
       }
    }
```

Comment: The -1 initializers have bug written all over them.

Comment: I eliminated the bug.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I find strange in your queue implementation...

Initializing front and rear to -1 is not a good idea.. Not so important, but the usual convention is to add elements to the front (the head) and remove from the rear (the tail).

```
class ArrayQueue
{
private:
   int data[MAX_SIZE];
   int front;
   int rear;
public:
   ArrayQueue()
   {
       front = -1;   // Why -1 and not 0 ??  See Enqueue ....
       rear = -1;    // front == rear is enough to indicate empty queue
   }

   void Enqueue(int element)
   {
       // Don't allow the queue to grow more
       // than MAX_SIZE - 1
       if ( Size() == MAX_SIZE - 1 )
           throw new QueueOverFlowException();

       data[rear] = element;  // <-- The first time around, rear == -1 !!

       // MOD is used so that rear indicator
       // can wrap around
       rear = ++rear % MAX_SIZE;  // maybe having a private incrementPtr() function 
                                  // would be a good idea.
   }

   int Dequeue(int n)  // what is n?? what does it do?
   {
       if ( isEmpty() )
           throw new QueueEmptyException();

       int ret = data[front];  // front == -1 the first time around. !!!

       // MOD is used so that front indicator
       // can wrap around
       front = ++front % MAX_SIZE;

       return ret;
   }

   int Front()   // could be const, since returning by value.
   {
       if ( isEmpty() )
           throw new QueueEmptyException();

       return data[front];
   }

   int Size()   // should be const
   {
       return abs(rear - front);  // There is definitely a problem here

       // correct way to compute # of elements:
       return (front >= rear) ? (front - rear) : (MAX_SIZE - (rear - front));

   }

   bool isEmpty()  // should be const
   {
       return ( front == rear ) ? true : false;  // redundant: (front == rear) 
                                                 // is already a bool
   }

   // no bool isFull() const function ? 
};
```